# Python openpyxl Table Styling convert table to range

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I generate this spreadsheet via python and pandas.  After generating the .xlsx file,
i would go into Excel and format it using the table Format as table button on the main ribbon.
I decided that i didn't want to manually format the spreadsheet so I started using Openpyxl to attempt to mimic my formats.

my main hiccup is that after i use the format as table button

I would then click on **Convert to Range**.

The problem is, i cant seem to be able to do this using openpyx.

Does anyone know how to do this? I don't want to create my own personalized style if one already exists.
this is the code i have been using

```
tab = Table(displayName="Final', ref='A1:O34', tableType=None)

style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleLight2", showFirstColumn=False,
showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=False)
tab.tablestyleInfo = style
ws.add_table(tab)
wb.save()
```

Very basic and to the point, more or less copied from teh openpyxl documents.

How do i convert this table to a range of values from openpyxl

thanks

Damn Groundhog

Comment: So you want the formatting of a table but not the functionality?

Comment: Exactly. I have been searching for a way to do this with the Table fucntionality in openpyxl, but can't find the ability to convert to range.  I fear that i would have to create my own style from scratch, which i will do if i have to but would like to avoid if necessary.

Comment: I don't think there's anything special about this but you'll have to apply the styles manually to all the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at xlsxwriter? It has an option to turn the [autofilter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html#autofilter) on/off when creating a table.

Comment: That's not what he's asking at all?